# Getting overlap of supply catchments using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.0, overlapping-features, catchment

I need to know, how much each of my calculated catchments is overlapped by the others, to assess the supply of the commodity per source point.

I calculated supply catchments for a total of 110 point features derived from an accessibility analysis for a specific commodity. That makes 110 catchment rasters with 3 classes OR 330 feature classes if converted to polygon by using the 3 classes.

I know the methodology to do it with intersect, but with this amount of layers it just takes too much time.

Any idea how to do it?

Comment: What takes long time? Computing overlaps of 300 polygons? It's a toy size set for ArcGis, unless they are not made of 100 k vertices each.

Comment: @FelixIP it takes long time because there are about ten steps I would all need to do individually. I need to calculate each of the 330 individual fc with each other fc. That makes 330^330 calculations. I just have not found an arcpy solution yet...

Comment: It can be done in one go, providing your polygons are stored in one feature class by using Union or intersect on itself. Perhaps rephrase your question ' how to convert 100 rasters to polygons' and assign unique names. Can be done in model builder.

Comment: And it is not 330 times 330 anyway, just a half of it:)

Comment: @FelixIP I already have the rasters and the polygons of the catchments, because I need both for another analysis. I cannot merge all the datasets to one feature class. ArcGIS gives me an error if I do that...